create azure functionapp from docker image via cli
I deployed an azure functionapp with the preview Flex Consumption plan, which doesn't include 'Site.SiteConfig.AlwaysOn' which i do not want.
When deploying via CLI like so:
az functionapp create --name $FUNCTION_APP_NAME --storage-account $STORAGE_ACCOUNT --resource-group $RESOURCE_GROUP 
--plan $FUNCTION_APP_SERVICE_PLAN --functions-version 4 
--image $ACR_NAME.azurecr.io/myimage:01 
--registry-password  
--registry-username 
I get this error:
The following site configuration property (Site.SiteConfig.AlwaysOn) for Flex Consumption sites is invalid.  Please remove or rename it before retrying.
I wonder, where the configuration property (Site.SiteConfig.AlwaysOn) comes from because i havn't set it anywhere. Hence a cannot remove or rename it.

Currently, the az functionapp create command does not allow the re-use of existing consumption plans.
Flex Consumption Plans can only be deployed by removing:
--plan planName

and substituting it with
--flexconsumption-location eastus

You'll want to set the correct region, of course. You can get all of the possible values by running:
az functionapp list-flexconsumption-locations

It's not ideal, but this should make the command work.
You can follow the state of this issue here.

Thank you.
It shows, that this works, if you add the runtime:
    az functionapp create `
    --name $NAME `
    --storage-account $STORAGEACCOUNT `
    --resource-group $GROUP `
    --flexconsumption-location $REGION `
    --runtime python

But provisioning a docker image when creating doesn't - according to the issue you mention above which states:
"Free tier does not work well with Functions because some triggers require always on enabled, and Free tier does not support it. The recommendation is to use Consumption."
